# DoctrineMongo near query

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have symfony 2 + doctrineMongo and i'm trying to use the geospatial query ->near but seems that this query don't work. Always return an empty array.

I followed this guide: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/mongodb_odm/1.0/en/reference/geospatial-queries.html

And i have this query in my repository:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('coordinates')->near($longitude, $latitude)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
```

There is a bug? How i can fix it?

My places findAll:

```
db.Place.find();

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e4b82df3eee4f7e2c000000"), "coordinates" : { "latitude" : 23.1, "longitude" : 23.23 }, "name" : "Opium Mar" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e5769f43eee4fc002000000"), "name" : "Sutton club", "coordinates" : { "latitude" : 2, "longitude" : 1 } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e5cf2173eee4fc202000008"), "name" : "Scorpia", "coordinates" : { "latitude" : 23, "longitude" : 22 } }
```

And this is my index:

```
db.system.indexes.find();

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.User", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.Place", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.Party", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.Friend", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.UserParty", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.Invite", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.Photo", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.Group", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "kzemos.places", "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "v" : 0 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e5deaced3c5c27e84059447"), "ns" : "kzemos.places", "key" : { "loc" : "2d" }, "name" : "loc_", "bits" : 26 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("4e5dead9d3c5c27e84059448"), "ns" : "kzemos.places", "key" : { "coordinates" : "2d" }, "name" : "coordinates_", "bits" : 26 }`
```

When i use the near query in mongo shell i get this error:

```
db.Place.find( { coordinates : { $near : [50,50] } } ) 

error: {
        "$err" : "can't find special index: 2d for: { coordinates: { $near: [ 50.0, 50.0 ] } }",
        "code" : 13038
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you run the `near` query in the mongo shell? Does it return anything?

Comment: Doing this query i get this error: `db.Place.find( { "coordinates" : { $near : [50,50] }})
error: {
        "$err" : "can't find special index: 2d for: { coordinates: { $near: [ 50.0, 50.0 ] } }",
        "code" : 13038
}`

Comment: The answer from Henrik Bjørnskov seems to be the solution. The error states the problem quite clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a Geospartial index on you collection like it is explained here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing